# Rear doorbell not working

Tags: doorbell

A neighbor ask me to help him figure out why his back doorbell isn't working. When I arrived, the back door button was gone. I know you should just be able to touch the wires together to get the chime to go off. The back doorbell wires go straight to the chime. The front doorbell wires go to the transformer. There is another set of wires at the transformer that go to the chime. The two reds are on the transformer and the whites are wire nutted together. The front doorbell works fine. I can't get my mind wrapped around this wiring setup.   My question is, will this set up work with the back doorbell wires going straight to the chime? I have tested the wires with an ohm meter so I know the wires go to the back door and they are not broke anywhere. Any ideas how I can wire this up without the wires from the back door going to the transformer?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The transformer-button red wire  is supply hot or "R" in thermostat speak.
The white wire is "front button switched-hot".
The chime-transformer red wire is return/common/neutral or "C" in thermostat speak.

You need to bring supply hot, and "rear button switched-hot" to the other doorbell.

...  presuming the doorbell has 2 different chimes.

Comment: Thanks Harper.  The doorbell chime does have two separate chimes for the back door and front door. I still cannot figure it out. I have touched the two wires coming from the back door to the three terminals on the chime and I cannot get it to do anything. That was with the wires twisted together at the back door.